# PHP throws a Fatal Error when trying to include/require a script that includes/requires another script

Tags: php, include, xampp, pear, require-once

That's basically it, as far as I can tell. I can include or require_once a script that has no includes/require_once, but if it does, then PHP throws me this error:

> Warning: require_once(../constants/constants.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Home\Workspace\PHP\DD\src\log\test.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../constants/constants.php' (include_path='.;C:\Program Files\Xampp 1.7.7\php\PEAR') in C:\Home\Workspace\PHP\DD\src\log\test.php on line 7

The path is correct. I fear I may have messed up some configuration file of the Apache Webserver (I created a .htaccess file to use mod_rewrite in order to create some better URLs).
The .htaccess file content is just this:

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule !.(gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php

My apache document root is "C:/Home/Workspace/PHP"

**UPDATE**:
I found out that using an absolute path works, like this:

> require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/DD/src/constants/constants.php";

I guess I'll just not use relative paths, then.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache.  The files which do the nested include must have the correct paths relative to themselves when including.  `../constants/constants.php` isn't in the right place based on the including file.

Comment: @Michael You should put this as answer. ;-) Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the current php-file's directory, regardless of the current working dir, which will be the same for all php-files even if they are in different directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that the relative paths are from the file with the first require/include. For example, if I had a group of files that looked like this:

```
|--bar
|   |--foo
|   |   |--foo.php
|   |--bar.php
|--test.php
```

if test.php had

```
require("./bar/bar.php")
```

and bar.php had

```
require("./foo/foo.php")
```

Then this would fail because the relative URLs must be relative to the working directory (the top file that called the require/include). If I changed bar.php to `require("./bar/foo/foo.php")` then the program would complete successfully. The best way to make sure this does not happen is to, as Basti stated, not use relative URLs. It is generally advisable to use various functions like `dirname(__FILE__)` to construct the URLs.

One last thing, the rewrite rule in the .htaccess file won't do anything, it only manipulates client side URLs. I hope that clears up any confusions.

Comment: I think I got it. I thought using relative paths was a good practice, but it seems I was mistaken. I tried using dirname(__FILE__), but it didn't work. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] seems to do it, though.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)`. Mind the two `_`. See [the PHP manual on magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for more information.

Comment: As of 5.3 php has `__DIR__` which is equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.